# Fixed elements in a permutation.

Tags: permutations, combinations

> Let, S = {A, B, C, D}. How many 3-elements' permutations can be formed from S were B and C both are always present.

**My attempted solution:**

$^4P_3 = \frac{4!}{(4-3)!} = 4! = 24$

Since, $2$ elements B and C are fixed, the result is, $\frac{24}{2!} = 12$.

---

Is this solution correct?

If not why?

Comment: @RobertZ That is a dangerous way to explain it.  It smells incredibly fishy to me and I expect that the logic is incorrect.  Perhaps you mean "The number of permutations with $A$ (*and $B$ and $C$*) is $3!$ and the number of permutations with $D$ (*and $B$ and $C$*) is $3!$, so the total number of permutations including $B$ and $C$ will be $3!+3!$"

Comment: @JMoravitz Your comment is incredibly better and clearer than mine! I going to remove it.

Comment: As an aside, a clean way to generalize the above argument would be to pick the collection of letters used and then pick how to line them up.  Using the same labels as below, this would be $\binom{n-r}{k-r}k!$

Comment: I find the wording to be poor. In the permutation (A,B,C)(D), the 1-cycle of (D) can be omitted, but just because an element is fixed by a permutation, doesn't mean it isn't "present".

Comment: Also, using the term "fixed" to refer to required elements is problematic, since "fixed", in the context of permutations, generally refers to elements that are unchanged by the permutation.

Comment: @accumulation it is an unfortunate thing, but it is sadly common for the word "permutation" to have a double meaning.  Here in this context it refers to a string consisting of various characters from a given set of a certain length such that order within the string is relevant and each character is used *at most* once.  The more standard meaning from group theory is that a permutation is a bijective function from a finite set to itself (*most commonly from [n] to [n]*) and can be reinterpreted as a string similar to before but where every element appears *exactly* once each.  Language evolves

Comment: As this second less precise meaning as a synonym for strings has become so common in elementary texts, I have lost the drive to continue to fight the change in the meaning of the word.  Which meaning is intended is generally clear from context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final numeral result is correct, but I am not sure yet if it is simply because of a fluke.  The (*presumed*) logic (*since you didn't explain where the formula you used comes from*) appears incorrect.  I much prefer avoiding division by symmetry arguments (*what I may have described as shepherd's principle to you or someone else before over the past few days*) whenever possible as it can be ambiguous *why* we are deciding to divide and requires extra steps to verify that the outcomes are infact counted the same number of times each extra.  Instead, we can approach directly via rule of product without any appeal to any other counting principles.

Step 1: Pick the location of the $B$:  $3$ options

Step 2: Pick the location of the $C$:  $2$ remaining options

Step 3: Pick the letter which occupies the final remaining position: $2$ remaining options

This gives $3\cdot 2\cdot 2=12$ total results.

---

As a test to see if your proposed formula is correct, it appears as though you intend that for $n$ letters and choosing $k$ of them such that $r$ are always present that the result would be $\dfrac{~^nP_k}{r!}$

The correct generalized formula, using the method I described above would come out to be $~^kP_r\cdot ~^{(n-r)}P_{(k-r)}$

This follows the same steps as above: Pick the location used by the "smallest" required letter.  Pick the location used by the second "smallest" required letter.... Pick the location used by the final required letter.  Pick the remaining letter to be used in the left-most unused space.  Pick the remaining letter to be used in the left-most remaining unused space..... Pick the remaining letter to be used in the final remaining space.

By plugging in some test values, these are indeed different expressions.  For example, it appears as though your proposed formula would give $\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{2}=60$ arrangements where we have $6$ letters, $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ that we want to take three of them but $B$ and $C$ both must be used, whereas my formula comes to $3\cdot 2\cdot 4=24$ arrangements.